# Change click.function() to an onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following script that works fine when I do the click function, but I need to change it so it will happen when the Web page loads. I could not find the answer to my problem searching through stackoverflow, so I would appreciate any help from anyone on how to change it.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() { //run on document.ready
      $("#current_sessioner").click(function() { //this occurs when select 1 changes
        $("#sessioner").val($(this).val());
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `$("#current_sessioner").click(function(){` and `});`? And replacing `$(this)` by `$("#current_sessioner")`?

Comment: just execute this line  $("#sessioner").val($(this).val()); delete the click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply move it out of the click handler.

```
$(function () {
  $("#sessioner").val($('#current_sessioner').val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bertrand! It worked just as you said. I'm so thankful for coders like yourself who take the time to help those who need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   $("#sessioner").val($('#current_sessioner').val());
}, false);
```

Comment: consider your consideration considered.

Comment: Thank you McGraw! It worked just as you said. I'm so thankful for coders like yourself who take the time to help those who need it.